# Should I protect my Angular controllers/services from global namespace?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller/services etc defined like the below as an example:

```
function IndexController($scope, shoppingItems) {
     $scope.items = shoppingItems;
 }
```

I then wondered whether all my JS should be proteted from the global namespace like so:

```
 (function() {

     function IndexController($scope, shoppingItems) {
         $scope.items = shoppingItems;
     }
 });
```

My app no longer works, can you explain if I need to do this or not and if so how to get it working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the new style of registering controllers(at least as of `1.0.3`, might be `1.0.1` as well)

```
(function() {
  //this will simulate creating the app with all needed dependencies
  var app = angular.module('app', ['my.dependecy1', 'my.dependecy1']);
  //...init code maybe
});

(function() {
  //this will only retrieve it or create if it it doesn't exist
  //I suggest you create it in another place passing all needed dependencies
  var app = angular.module('app');

  //I also recommend listing injectable variables manually,
  //this way if you ever need minification you're safe
  app.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', 'shoppingItems', 
     function IndexController($scope, shoppingItems) {
         $scope.items = shoppingItems;
     }
  ]);

}());
```

Comment: What do you mean by "create it in another place passing all needed dependencies" ? Thanks

Comment: Basically create it in another file/scope to make sure you can easily move code around

Comment: Ah ok, does that mean I dont have to decare some many JS files in my index.html page or is that different again?

Comment: you could have 1 huge js file containing all the code inside a single (function() {}()) but I found it's better to split functionality early in development so it's easier to modularize it later

Comment: Thanks. In the docs here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di it says to declare controllers differently and use MyController.$inject in the "Where can I use DI?" section. Who's right you or the docs :)

Comment: Both are "right" since below it says the alternative is provided to reduce code bloat. Also it exposes an extra variable that needs to be contained less it pollutes the global namespace. Both work btw and at some point you need to decide which style you like best.

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a pair of parenthesis at the end, making your function an immediately evaluated function :

```
(function() {
     function IndexController($scope, shoppingItems) {
         $scope.items = shoppingItems;
     }
 })();
```

Comment: Still doesn't work unfortunately - IndexController is not defined from 'myCart'

Comment: well that's the whole point of "hiding" your code from global namespace. IndexController is now hidden and in only defined in the (function(){ .....  })(); block. I thought this was example code, please post more details/code about what you need .

Comment: I thought it was best practice not to put things globally hence why I tried to do it, that's all